# CSS class to button with double parallelograms as background

Tags: html, css

I need a help with writing css class. I want to create button as it is shown on image below. There is screenshot with dimensions.

First parallelogram is:

```
height: 52px;
width: 235px;
background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FEE195 0%, #FFD361 100%);
```

Second one:

```
height: 52px;
width: 26px;
left: 222px;
background: #FFFFFF;
```

Text is in the middle of the first one.

[image]

Comment: Can you please include your HTML and CSS code?

Comment: I have edited the post. I've attached everything I have. They are vector images and I want to make a <button></buttn> with background as shown on screenshot.

Comment: Have a go at coding this using the CSS you already have and some HTML - div or button or something and see how far you can get then when you are stuck put the code into your question as a [link]https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example which will help us help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a button with the "double parallelogram" background, your on the right track using [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()). You can style a `<button>` element using linear-gradient with [color stops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient()#gradient_with_multi-position_color_stops) to create the parallelogram background you shared. I used an arbitrary `width: 180px` but you can adjust your color stops in the linear gradient to whichever width you end up choosing.

```css
body {
  background-color: #252525;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background: linear-gradient(68deg, #000 0% 10%, #FEE195 10% 30%, #FEE195 30% 83%, #000 83% 86%, #fff 86% 90%, #000 90%);
}
```

```html
<button class="custom-bg">Some Text</button>
```